# changing friction in c# Unity

Tags: c#, 2d, unityscript

I am working on a project in my game programming class, and I want to change the friction of a physics2D material, and I can't find anything about changing it. Do you need to import anything, and what would the code be? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can do this.

[From the UI](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsMaterial2D.html)

From the code (in C#)

`gameObject.GetComponent(CircleCollider2D).sharedMaterial.friction = 0.0f`

Where gameObject is your gameObject

Refs

- [Physics Material 2d](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsMaterial2D.html)
- [Box Collider 2d](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BoxCollider2D.html)
- [Shared Material](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D-sharedMaterial.html)

Comment: Are you sure that works? Doesn't for me.